# Cannot import pandas_profiling library

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to practice EDA, I have installed pandas-profiling successfully in jupyter notebook but I am getting an import error while importing it.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
```

I am using the latest version of python: Python 3.11.2
and pandas version is 1.5.3
The pandas-profiling version is 3.2.0

Any kind of help would be appreciated:)

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 import pandas
----> 2 import pandas_profiling

File E:\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py:6
      1 """Main module of pandas-profiling.
      2 
      3 .. include:: ../../README.md
      4 """
----> 6 from pandas_profiling.controller import pandas_decorator
      7 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
      8 from pandas_profiling.version import __version__

File E:\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\controller\pandas_decorator.py:4
      1 """This file add the decorator on the DataFrame object."""
      2 from pandas import DataFrame
----> 4 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
      7 def profile_report(df: DataFrame, **kwargs) -> ProfileReport:
      8     """Profile a DataFrame.
      9 
     10     Args:
   (...)
     15         A ProfileReport of the DataFrame.
     16     """

File E:\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\profile_report.py:15
     13 from pandas_profiling.config import Config, Settings
     14 from pandas_profiling.expectations_report import ExpectationsReport
---> 15 from pandas_profiling.model.alerts import AlertType
     16 from pandas_profiling.model.describe import describe as describe_df
     17 from pandas_profiling.model.sample import Sample

File E:\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\model\alerts.py:10
      7 import pandas as pd
      9 from pandas_profiling.config import Settings
---> 10 from pandas_profiling.model.correlations import perform_check_correlation
     13 @unique
     14 class AlertType(Enum):
     15     """Alert types"""

File E:\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\model\correlations.py:8
      6 import pandas as pd
      7 from multimethod import multimethod
----> 8 from pandas.core.base import DataError
     10 from pandas_profiling.config import Settings
     13 class Correlation:

ImportError: cannot import name 'DataError' from 'pandas.core.base' (E:\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the version compatibility between pandas-profiling and pandas. The latest version of pandas-profiling version 3.2.0 might not be compatible with the version of pandas you are using version 1.5.3

You can install version 2.11.0 of pandas-profiling using the following command

```
!pip install pandas-profiling==2.11.0
```

Or you can try downgrading to an older version

```
pip install pandas==1.2.4
```

Comment: For running install commands in an `.ipynb` file, you should be suggesting best practices of using the modern magics that insure the installation is done in the environment backing the kernel underlying the notebook. See about the modern magic `%pip install` command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). Avoid suggesting use of the exclamation point for installs as it can lead to issues, ...

Comment: <continued> see the second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). To summarize: `!pip install pandas-profiling==2.11.0` **should be better suggested as:** `%pip install pandas-profiling==2.11.0`

Comment: Thankyou, my issue got resolved .